# Disable abort call when throwing bad alloc in std library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I'm trying to write a custom allocator to get better code coverage for branches that are executed only when OOM occurs. I managed to write the allocator, but when a bad_alloc is thrown on debug inside a class from std, an internal call to abort is made. This behavior is only on debug, on release I can run the tests.

Is there any way to disable this behavior on debug configuration?

### Update #1

This is a code snippet where the problem described above occurs. I also forgot to mention that I use MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool throw_bad_alloc = false;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    if (throw_bad_alloc)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    return ::malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
    ::free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    try {
        throw_bad_alloc = true;
        std::string name;
        name = "test_string";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "thrown";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "not thrown";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) is typically called as part of [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). And `std::terminate` is called when exceptions are not handled. How do you handle exceptions, more specifically the `std::bad_alloc` exception?

Comment: The test function is wrapped in a try-catch block. On release all tests are runned, with `std::bad_alloc` being thrown multiple times in every function, the problem is only on debug.